# Combinatorial Problem: How many ordered pairs of distinct but overlapping ordered pairs do exist?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a universe of $n$ numbers. How many ordered pairs of ordered pairs, that is, $((a,b), (c,d))$ with $a\neq b$, $c \neq d$ do exist such that $(a,b)\neq (c,d)$ but 
either

$a=c$,

or $b=d$,

or $a=d$ and $b=c$.

I thought there were $2{n \choose 1}{{n-1} \choose 1}{{n-2} \choose 1}+{n \choose 1}{{n-1} \choose 1}$ many, since for the first two cases one can choose the common element and then the other two each separately and multiply it by 2 to get the case $a=c$ or $b=d$. For the third case, two elements can be Chosen.

But it seems as this is wrong and the correct answer should be $2{n \choose 3}+{n \choose 2}$, but why?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you tell us where you got the "correct" answer from?

Comment: Also,why don't you experiment with small sets and see what you get?

Comment: I experimented with small sets and got my answer. 
The "correct" answer is not directly available as I simplified the Problem to put it here, but one can find it on 
https://www.ceid.upatras.gr/webpages/courses/probmethweb/lessons/lesson7.pdf, page 13, where the number of elements there is $n-2$.

Comment: For example for $n=3$, I get that one can have :
$(1,2)$, $(2,1)$ AND 

$(1,2)$, $(1,3)$ AND

$(1,2)$, $(3,1)$.
And likewise, for every possible righthern pair, thus ${3 \choose 2} 2 = 6$ pairs. 
I get thus $6 \cdot 3 = 18$ such combinations, and 
$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 2=12 +6 = 18$. 

But the solution would be $2 \cdot 1 + 2 =4$ only?

Comment: ,I believe your answer is correct.Since both logic and empirical evidence points to your answer,I think your solution is right.

Comment: so it means it is one of These three cases, where the third case consists of two conditions. 

I think overlapping is not enough.

you can have the following Intuition for it:

Let $u, v$ be two nodes in a graph. Now i am interested in the paths of length 3 between $u$ and $v$. Then there must be $2$ nodes $x,y$ in between such that $u,x,y,v$ is a path.

Now we are interested in the number of node pairs $(x,y)$ such that there is a dependency between the paths. Thus they must not only overlap but overlap such that there are two vertices that are the same or in reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view this as counting oriented arcs in a graph defined on $[n]\times[n]\setminus\Delta$ (where $[n]$ denotes the $n$-elements "universe" which I will take to be $n$ consecutive integers, and where $\Delta=\{\,(x,x)\mid x\in[n]\,\}$ is the diagonal of $[n]\times[n]$). The description says that every point has an arc to each other point in its row, to each other point in its column, and to its image reflected in $\Delta$ (the point with switched coordinates). Since the diagonal is missing, that makes $(n-2)+(n-2)+1=2n-3$ outgoing arcs from each point. There are $n(n-1)$ points (they all have the same number of outgoing arcs), which makes $$n(n-1)(2n-3)=2n^3-5n^2+3n$$ oriented arcs in all (for non-oriented arcs, divide by $2$).

This equals $n(n-1)(2(n-2)+1)$ (your answer), but not $2\binom n3+\binom n2$, which cannot be right because it is not always even.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
 a=c and b=c
 All pairs of the form ((x,x),(x,y)),y not equal to x. Thus x can be selected in n ways corresponding to each such selection y in n-1 ways. Thus, there are n(n-1) ways. [Note: Here(( x,y),(x,x))will destroy the propety]

Case 2:
b=d and b= c 
All pairs of the form ((x,y),(y,y))and x not equal to y. One again y can be selected in n ways and corresponding to which x in n-1 ways. There are n(n-1) ways and all are different from case 1.

Case 3:
a=d and b=c
All pairs of the form ((x,y),(y,x)), x not equal to y. There are n ways of selction for x and for each selection  n-1 ways for y. Thus there are n(n-1) ways of selection. All these are different from case 1 and 2

Thus there will be total of 3n(n-1) ordered pairs of ordered pairs.

Comment: Sorry! I should have added that I want that $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$, that is, I really want pairs, so I do not allow a pair $(1,1)$ for example.

Comment: Then it seems that you are correct!